# Dynamically add entries to alexa custom slot type s

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, slot

I have developed an Alexa skill and in one of the intents made it a to have a custom slot type. The custom slot type is nothing but a very specific, specialized list of strings.

My question is how to dynamically add entries to the list, is there an API on Amazon side that I could call from my code to dynamically add new entries and retain the model?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you cannot add slots dynamically. You have to configure manually in interaction model.

Comment: Is there any reference for this?

Comment: I have tried it before and did some read in aws  developer forum. Please see this - https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/9249/allow-dynamic-values-for-slots.html